# Remove buffering activity indicator from AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, uiactivityindicatorview, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm implementing an iOS video player using `AVPlayerViewController` with custom playback controls (i.e., the `showsPlaybackControls` property is defined as `NO`). This seems to work properly in most cases, the only issue I'm seeing is that I would like to use a custom activity indicator with the player as well, but it seems that `AVPlayerViewController` shows a default activity indicator while buffering the video at some points.

Is there a way to remove this default activity indicator view from `AVPlayerViewController`?

The image shows what I'm describing, the controls at the bottom are custom and overlaid on top of the player, but the activity indicator is not.

[image: player with custom controls and default activity indicator]

Comment: I hope someone can help, I'm trying to do the same thing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made an extension of `AVPlayerViewController` that exposes the internal activity indicator. Here you go, with all the Swift 3 sexiness:

```
import AVKit

extension AVPlayerViewController {
    /// Activity indicator contained nested inside the controller's view.
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView? {
        // Indicator is extracted by traversing the subviews of the controller's `view` property.
        // `AVPlayerViewController`'s view contains a private `AVLoadingIndicatorView` that
        // holds an instance of `UIActivityIndicatorView` as a subview.
        let nestedSubviews: [UIView] = view.subviews
            .flatMap { [$0] + $0.subviews }
            .flatMap { [$0] + $0.subviews }
            .flatMap { [$0] + $0.subviews }
        return nestedSubviews.filter { $0 is UIActivityIndicatorView }.first as? UIActivityIndicatorView
    }

    /// Indicating whether the built-in activity indicator is hidden or not.
    var isActivityIndicatorHidden: Bool {
        set {
            activityIndicator?.alpha = newValue ? 0 : 1
        }
        get {
            return activityIndicator?.alpha == 0
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you can either easily style the `UIActivityIndicatorView` or just hide it all together, e.g.:

```
playerViewController.isActivityIndicatorHidden = true
```

Comment: getting error : "Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Comment: Very easy to solve, just break it into several expressions. So don't do every `flatMap` on the same line, create intermittent variables.

Answer (score 1):

I also searched for this solution and the way I managed to make it is hide video player view controllers view once I started playing video and when video is ready to play I show it again.

```
private func playVideo() {

    videoPlayer?.play()

    self.addLoader()

    videoPlayerController.view.hidden = true

    videoPlayer?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "status", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
}

public override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

    if (object?.isEqual(videoPlayer) == true && keyPath == "status") {

        self.removeLoader()
        videoPlayerController.view.hidden = false
    }
}
```